# count chars between <> tags in XML

Tags: xml, count, char, xmlstarlet

i'm not experienced user of Linux and have a big problem. I need to count all chars in XML file exept tags.

for example

```
<node>
 <node1>Text</node>
</node>
```

My output should return 4 or Text. I try to figure out

> xmlstarlet

programm but i cant use it even after read manual.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xml sel -t -v 'string-length(/*)' file.xml
```

should give you the total number of characters of text content within the root element (*including* whitespace, so that would be 7 in your example - newline, space, T, e, x, t, newline).  This would only be characters in text nodes, so would not include comments or processing instructions, i.e.

```
<foo>This is a <!-- simple --> example</foo>
```

would give you a length of 18.

Comment: `--noblanks` or `-B` would remove whitespace only nodes

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. Can you tell me where I can find anything about `'string-length(/*)'` part of formula? It's some function built in Linux or Starlet itself?

Comment: @Glorifind it's an [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) expression. `/*` selects the root element node (whatever it is named), `string-length` converts this to a string (which in the case of an element node is defined as concatenating together all the descendant text nodes at all levels in the tree) and returns the number of characters that string contains.